# Help identifying an insect

Tags: zoology, entomology

I live in Milan, Italy in the city center. I live in this house since 5 years and I keep finding the insect pictured below.

I see it throughout the seasons (temperatures here range from -1°C to +35°C in average).

I find it mostly in my bathroom which is not well ventilated and it is the warmest room in the house (about 23°C in winter even with the radiators off and up to 35°C in summer during very hot days if I don't use air conditioning).

The size is about 7mm in length and 1mm in width (including only the main body, i.e., excluding legs and antennae).

I find it mostly during the night but maybe just because I use brighter lights and I can see it more clearly on my white walls.

What is its name so I can research more about it (i.e., does it pose any risk to my health or to my belongings in the house?)?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a species of silverfish.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygentoma

[image]

They eat paper, cloth and stored foods like cereal, even organic wall paste, so yes they can damage your stuff, but outside allergies they are harmless to a person.

Comment: Could it be also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebrat ?

Comment: Zygentoma is the name of the group there are several species, look at your local pest identification.  silverfish is the common name.

Comment: @John ‘Silverfish’ is the common name for _a number of_ species in the Zygentoma group, but not all. Firebrats are, in my experience, the primary exclusion from the term, since their defining feature is that they’re **not** silvery to look at, but brownish-grey. Sort of like how members of the Odonata family are mostly called dragonflies, except those that are called damselflies.

Comment: Silverfish is what immediately leaped to mind when I saw the picture.